# Jquery Dropdown Menu for Mobile Losing CSS Attributes

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

Possibly quite a simple fix here

I am working with Jquery for some dropdown text for a site that I'm working on (I'm fairly amateur with coding in general)

The function seems to work on mobile devices, yet I lose all the css attributes to the text so all the design goes to default. However it's working completely fine on web browser

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="paragraphAnchor" class="text">
<img src="images/definition-02.png" style="top:-20px; left:6%;
position:absolute; width:40%; max-width:194px;"></a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="paragraphAnchor">

<p id="info">
Lorem Ipsum 
</p>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#info {

font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:13px;
max-width:460px;
width:80%;
left:6%;
top:40px;
padding:6px;
letter-spacing:0em;
color:#666;
background-color:white;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #CCCCCC;
border-radius:4px;
border:0px solid #333;
position:absolute;
z-index:2000px;
}

#info a {

font-family: Helvetica;
font-size:13px;
color:#333;
text-decoration:none;

}
```

Any pointers would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Mobile Related jQuery Plugins are below.

1. http://jquerymobile.com/
2. http://jqtjs.com/
3. http://phonegap.com/

Comment: I mean the original query function is working on mobile it's just losing it's style attributes for some reason

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: It's ok just used the stylesheet from the code which worked great